# Using 256 colors in Go

Tags: windows, go, colors

How Can I used 256 colors in terminal with Golang.

As Libraries like faith/color only have limited colors support.

This python library  [here](https://github.com/a-polyglot/256-color/blob/main/Color.py)

use some kind of default code and a color code to print colored text in terminal.

I try to use color code but instead of color it printing color code in go program but in python program it prints colored text.

How can I print color use color code as above library doing...

Do I need to initialize the terminal ? If yes How?

Thanks!

I am expecting 256 colors to print in terminal.

*go version: 1.18.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows can be weird. In some cases you need to set the console mode. If you are using Windows, specify it as part of your question.

`colors.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    setConsoleColors()

    for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 16; j++ {
            code := strconv.Itoa(i*16 + j)
            color := "\u001b[38;5;" + code + "m"
            fmt.Printf("%s %-4s", color, code)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Print("\u001b[0m")
}
```

`colors_windows.go`:

```
//go:build windows

package main

import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

func setConsoleColors() error {
    console := windows.Stdout
    var consoleMode uint32
    windows.GetConsoleMode(console, &consoleMode)
    consoleMode |= windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
    return windows.SetConsoleMode(console, consoleMode)
}
```

`colors_other.go`:

```
//go:build !windows

package main

func setConsoleColors() error {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I just need to initialize the terminal before prinitng colors.

Comment: Also sometimes you need to specify the .exe suffix to the interpreter and I don't entirely know why. There's a post here about it somewhere but I can't seem to find it right now. But like if you were, say, using python, `python.exe myprogram` would enable ansi colors but `python myprogram` wouldn't. Same with `node.exe` vs `node`, etc.